# How do I call a nested function in a parent document from an iframe

Tags: javascript

In parent:

```
function outer(){
    function inner(){
        alert("hello");
    }
}
```

in iframe

```
parent.outer.inner();
```

does not work.

Edit: So they are private. No problem. The reason for doing this is to try and hide these functions from global scope as much as possible. I thought putting them behind a single function name with a pretty unique name would be the best way to do this.

Essentially do I need to

parent:

```
function outer(action){

    if(action == "inner")
       inner()

    function inner(){
        alert("hello");
    }
}
```

iframe:
    parent.outer("inner");

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: If you want the inner() function to be callable from outside the outer() function, you have to make a reference to it trough closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested functions are private and you can at best only specify arguments for inner functions outside the outer function.

Explanation can be found here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope
under "Nested functions and closures"

Answer (score 0):

This seems to answer my edit fairly well
[How to turn a String into a javascript function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call)

Answer (score 0):

By using closure :

```
   function outer(){
        function inner(){
        alert("I am Inner");
        }
        return inner ;
   }
   var x = outer();
   x();
```

If you want to use variable of inner function than we can do in this way :

```
  function outer(){
        function inner(){
         var y=10;  return y;    
       }
       return inner ;
 }
 var x = outer();
 x();
```

Answer (score -1):

One approach is using an object

```
function Outer(){
    this.inner = function(){
        alert("hello");
    }
}

var o = new Outer()
o.inner();
```