# Invoke JavaScript function with argument via pointer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

How can you invoke a function in JavaScript, while passing in arguments, using a function pointer?

Example:

```
function foo (a, callback) {    
        jQuery.post('/soon/check.json', { var:a }, function(resp) {
             callback(resp);
    }); 
}

function process_json(resp) {
  // Do something with resp
}

foo(bar, process_json);
```

`process_json` never gets invoked. Looking in Firebug, the string `process_json` is getting passed into `foo`, but I assumed this represents a pointer to the function `process_json`.

In Javascript, is it not possible to invoke functions via pointers and pass in arguments?

Comment: There's no reason to wrap `callback` in an anonymous function. `$.post('/soon/check.json', {var : a}, callback)` should work just as well.

Comment: Are you sure the ajax call is successful? If there was an error then your callback won't be hit.

Comment: jQuery.post's callback takes three params, the second of which is a text message describing the status of the request. Making AJAX calls without checking that the request succeeded and the result is valid is very bad programming practice.

Comment: @Rob the callback to `$.post()` is only invoked on success.

Comment: *blush* Ouch, you're right. So, OP would need to refactor to consider events.

Comment: Long story short, we do want to pass in a string instead of the function pointer ... is it possible to invoke the function just knowing its name (through the string)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In Javascript, is it not possible to invoke functions via pointers and pass in arguments?

It most certainly is possible to do this. Everything about your code looks just fine to me. Are you sure that the `$.post()` callback (the anonymous function) is being called? Is `bar` undefined when `foo` is invoked?

> To clarify, we need to invoke a function using a string -- not a function pointer. Is this possible?

Yes. If the function is defined globally, you can invoke it as a property on the `window` object, like so:

```
function foo () { /* snip */ }

var fn_name = 'foo';

window.foo();       // works
window['foo']();    // works
window[fn_name]();  // also works
```

Comment: Bar is defined. Yes, jQuery.post() is being called. This bug confuses us, too. The only other thing not mentioned is foo and process_json are in different javascript files, but process_json is available to foo (a javascript file gets included in the page where foo lives, and process_json is where this file lives).

Comment: @Crash: does the actual `$.post` pass `{ var:a }`? That will ***definitely*** break things because `var` is a keyword.

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot. We were passing a string instead of the function pointer ... I would delete this question because it's too stupid to remain on SO, but I feel like I should award points to someone. Sorry for the waste of time, haha.

Comment: To clarify, we need to invoke a function using a string -- not a function pointer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
var process_json = function(resp) {
  // Do something with resp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/26naf/

Function `alert` is passed to foo by reference:

```
function foo(fref)
{
   fref("hi world");
}

foo(alert);
```

And it works as you see.

Comment: lol yes, but not in the same way. and the OP is passing a string `"alert"` not the literal `alert`

Comment: c-smile is right. We're passing in a function pointer, not a string. But for some reason it appears like a string in Firebug (though maybe we didn't look carefully at Firebug). We are definitely not (deliberately) passing in a string. Just the function pointer.

Comment: @Neal no, I don't believe the OP is passing a string.

Comment: @MattBall - i quote: `" the string "process_json" is getting passed into "foo,""`

Comment: Sorry, I'm an idiot. We were passing a string instead of the function pointer ... I would delete this question because it's too stupid to remain on SO, but I feel like I should award points to someone. Sorry for the waste of time, haha.

Comment: @Neal Long story short, we do want to pass in a string instead of the function pointer ... is it possible to invoke the function just knowing its name (through the string)?

Comment: @Neal, aren't you just passing in the function pointer to alert as opposed to the string "alert?"

Comment: To clarify, we need to invoke a function using a string -- not a function pointer.

Comment: @CrashAlot, nope thats a string, to see the function method look at the fiddle in this answer

Comment: Found this, @Neal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call

Comment: @Neal, sorry about that! We clicked on c-smile's fiddle -- not yours.

Comment: @Neal ... hence all the confusion. Sorry. Need more caffeine this morning, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can pass in functions as callbacks, in fact by doing

```
jQuery.post('/soon/check.json', { var:a }, function(resp) {...
```

You are passing a callback that will be called after the post.

So the problem is somewhere else. Is the anonymous function passed to `$.post` really called ?

Hope this will help