# executing a list of functions by their function name

Tags: javascript

I have several functions that are used to bind events with divs on the page. There's MenuHandlers, CalendarHandlers, PopupHandlers....

So for the moment, I have a single function that's called BindHandlers that I call from the document ready function and that runs all the handler functions one by one.

Is there a one-liner solution that would say something like "call all the functions that have "Handlers" in their function name?

Here's what the function looks like:

```
function BindHandlers() {
  MenuHandlers();
  CalendarHandlers();
  PopupHandlers();
  ... 8 more like this
}
```

What I'm looking to replace:

```
BindHandlers(); // replace that line with the following:
"call all the functions that have "Handlers" in their names
```

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Why would you want to do it any other way? It couldn't possibly be any faster than just doing it one by one.

Comment: Are those functions global functions or properties of one of your objects?

Comment: beccause that way, if I add Handlers functions, they'll just get executed automatically.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: they're all globals

Comment: Look at these answers for inspiration:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: @frenchie The use of global variables should be minimized. Wrap your script in `(function () {...})` at least...

Comment: Look at these answers for inspiration:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object

Comment: Let us see that part of the `BindHandlers`-code where the other handlers are called. It seems like those handlers are called inproperly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If these functions are all global, you *could* call all functions with `Handlers` in the name with something like this

```
for (var x in window)
    if (typeof window[x] === 'function' && /Handlers/.test(x))
         window[x]();
```

Here's a [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Dy7/)

Comment: Ok, that's really cool; not a one-liner but still solves the problem of having to register the handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone has this:

```
events: {
    'click #menu'       : 'MenuHandler',
    'click #calendar'   : 'CalendarHandler',
    // etc.
}
```

The event binding is performed automatically when the corresponding view is created.

You could use this pattern:

```
bindEvents({
    'click #menu'       : 'MenuHandler',
    'click #calendar'   : 'CalendarHandler',
    // etc.
});
```