# Send function name, before they are loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code, where I pass the jsFile name to load and the java script function to call in it. But as the function is still not loaded, so I have to send string names and use this type of switch statements.

```
$.getScript(jsFile, function() {
    switch(initFunc){
        case 'a':
            a();
            break;
        case 'b':
            b();
            break;
    };
});
```

Is there anyway this can be simplified, I don't want conditional statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to turn a String into a javascript function call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script being loaded defines these as global functions (which the use of `a()` and `b()` seems to suggest it does), you can utilize `window` as the global object in browsers:

```
$.getScript(jsFile, function () {
    window[initFunc]();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass both the name of the script and the name of the callback function to a wrapper that looks something like this:

```
function loadNExecute(scriptName, callbackName) {
  $.getScript(scriptName, function() {
    window[callbackName]();
  });
}
```

You would of course need to ensure that the script is loaded successfully and adjust the parent of the callback function (`window`, in the example above) to suit your needs.