# Calling function by name (as a string) within an object literal in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am currently building something in JS and have run into the following scenario:

```
// these are set programmatically, not like this, just using as an example
var data = {'someData':'blah'};
var widget = 'NameOfWidget';
var command = 'someFunctionName';

// there is a base object that has all widgets and their commands as child objects
// format would be like: UBER.WidgetName.command(data);
// here is how I have tried to call it thus far
UBER[widget][command](data);
window['UBER'][widget][command](data);
```

I feel like I am close to figuring it out, just need a little help in figuring out exact syntax! Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call

Comment: Tell me what `var_dump(UBER.widget.command)` gives you?

Comment: All of those attempts are correct syntax, assuming that your `UBER` object is structured like that.  So if it's not working, clearly your object is not structured like that.  Try doing a `console.log(UBER)` in something like the Chrome developer console, and explore that object a bit to see what it's like inside.  If you still can't figure it out, report back what you see after the `console.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
UBER['widget']['command'](data); 
window['UBER']['widget']['command'](data);
```

or

```
UBER.widget.command(data);
window.UBER.widget.command(data);
```

This assumes command is a function, widget and UBER are objects, and window['UBER'] = UBER.

When you are referencing object properties using bracket syntax, you need to use a string.  If using `.` syntax, you must use a legal string literal that is not a reserved word in Javascript.

For example:

```
var command = function(){return 5},
    widget = {},
    UBER = {};
UBER.widget = widget;
widget.command = command;
console.log(UBER['widget']['command']()); // prints 5 to Chrome's developer console or firebug
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not doing this?

```
window[UBER.widget.command](data);
```

Edit: I see what you're trying to do, this answer <strike>is currently incorrect</strike> should work, given that I understand what you're attempting to do.