# How to pass a web service to javascript as a string?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services

I currently have an ajax custom control that makes calls to a web service as part of its functionality.  I need to pass which web service to call to the control as a parameter.  Currently, I'm using a string parameter in the .vb file and passing it to the javascript.  I execute the calls to the web service by building a line as a string, then using eval() on it.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call), I can see that eval is bad.  Like the function calls on that page, is there any way that I can use the web service as something that I can call?

Note, I am calling methods from the web service.  Instead of stringservice(parameters), it is stringservice.start(parameters).  And I just get the error that strings don't have a start method.

Any solution, or am I stuck using eval?  Thanks :)

Comment: Please show us the codes that build the function string.

Comment: Currently it's just like this:  
`var starter = this.WebService + '.Begin(this.ProcessID, this.ProcessName, params);';  

eval(beginProcess);`  


But it seems that I should be using JSON format?  I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is in the JSON format, you can safely convert it using `JSON.parse`

Comment: Thank you!  Will I still be able to make calls to the different methods?

Comment: Sorry, but I dint get your question

Comment: Currently in the eval, I just call `service.method(parameters);`   Will it still work like that with the JSON?

Comment: If your JSON string has an object `service` and if that object `method` as a function, then yes

Answer (score 1):

You can access properties of the global object with the [bracket syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) as well:

```
window[this.WebService](this.ProcessID, this.ProcessName, params);
```

However, I'd recommend to bundle the available functions in an object of webservices, like

```
var webservices = {
    a: function(id, name, params) { ... },
    b: function(id, name, params) { ... },
    ...
};

...

webservices[this.WebService](this.ProcessID, this.ProcessName, params);
```

Comment: Will this method still work for method calls?   Like, can I use `webservices[this.WebService].Begin();`?  Or would it work if I put the begin within the webservice.  Ex:  `this.WebService = 'testservice.begin'`?  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yes, when a property points to an object you can access that ones properties with dot syntax again. The second one won't work, this is exactly the case for property names containing invalid identifier characters like dots, brackets etc.