# Is it possible to call a method from an object using a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, methods, eval

Is it possible to call a method from an object using a string?

```
var elem = $('#test');             //<div id="test"></div>
var str = "attr('id')";  

//This is what I'm trying to achieve
  elem.attr('id');                 //test

//What I've tried so far  
  elem.str;                        //undefined
  elem.str();                      //Object [object Object] has no method 'str'
  var fn = eval(str);              //attr is not defined
  eval(elem.toString()+'.'+str);   //Unexpected identifier

//Only solution I've found so far, 
//but is not an option for me 
//because this code is in a function 
//so the element and method call
//get passed in and I wouldn't know
//what they are
  eval($('#test').attr('id'));     //test
```

Comment: did you try alert(elem+'.'+str);

Comment: @AshirvadSingh - that displays `[object Object].attr('id')`

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call

Comment: @Aby - Yes I have seen that. That works for calling functions from a string but I am looking to call methods of an object from a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This is my final, working answer:
After running this code in the console

```
theMethod = 'attr("id","foo")'.match(/^([^(]+)\(([^)]*)\)/);
jQuery('#post-form')[theMethod[1]].apply(jQuery('#post-form'),JSON.parse('['+theMethod[2]+']'));
```

The post-form element now has a new ID, no problems at all. This works for methods that take multiple arguments, a single argument or no arguments at all. Recap:

```
theMethod = theInString.match(/^\.?([^(]+)\(([^)]*)\)/);
//added \.? to trim leading dot
//made match in between brackets non-greedy
//dropped the $ flag at the end, to avoid issues with trailing white-space after )
elem[theMethod[1]].apply(elem,JSON.parse('['+theMethod+']'));
```

That's the safest, most reliable approach I can think of, really

---

What ever you do ***DON'T USE EVAL***:

```
var theMethod = 'attr(\'id\')';
//break it down:
theMethod = theMethod.match(/^([^(]+)\(.*?([^)'"]+).*\)$/);
//returns ["attr('id')", "attr", "id"]
elem[theMethod[1]](theMethod[2]);//calls the method
```

It's the same basic principle as you'd use with *any* objects (remember that functions are objects all on their own in JS - and jQuery objects are, well, objects, too). This means that methods can be accessed in the exact same way as properties can:

```
$('#foo').attr('id') === $('#foo')['attr']('id');
```

So just break the string apart, and use the method name like you would an object property and you're all set to go.

Just remember: ***When all you have is the eval hammer, everything looks like your thumb.*** 
*Brendan Eich*

---

If there is a chance of multiple arguments being passed to whatever method, you can sort of work your way around that, too (I think - well: logic dictates, but it's rather late and logic is getting beat up by Gin pretty bad now):

```
theMethod = theMethod.match(/^([^(]+)\(([^)]+)\)$/);
//["attr('id','foo')", "attr", "'id','foo'"] --> regex must now match quotes, too
elem.theMethod[1].apply(elem,JSON.parse('['+theMethod[2]+']'));
```

This applies the method of whatever element/object you're dealing with to itself, thus not changing the caller context (`this` will still point to the object within the method) and it passes an array of arguments that will be passed to the called method.

Comment: You can't reliably split args on the comma since there could be other commas within the arguments. `'func(greet("Elias", "Hi, how are you"), /(.*?),.*/)'`

Comment: Fair enough, that was just a wild stab in the dark, with a bit of work, and a lot less of drink I could write an expression to to split the arguments reliably, though. Nevertheless, you could just `JSON.parse('["foo","bar"]')` in that case: `elem,theMethod[2].apply(elem,JSON.parse('['+theMethod[2]+']'));` would work just fine, wouldn't it? Ha, just thought of it, it's even better than splitting... I'm editing my answer! Hooray for GIN!

Comment: JSON data represents only a narrow subset of possible syntax that could appear. Things like `undefined`, identifiers, regexs, anonymous functions and function calls will break it. I think it will come down to either parsing the JavaScript, or using `eval`.

Comment: How likely is it that you'll start of with a string, that contains a function definition/declaration that you'll then need to pass as an argument to a jQ method? if the answer to this is _very_, then I'm sorry but there's something wrong with the way your tackling your problem... But that's just what how I feel about that, and yes, then eval becomes pretty much a necessity. Though you're jumping right into the most dangerous of usages of eval: eval-ing to create new functions... ouch

Comment: While you're on this site, type this in your console `eval('$ = function(){return null;}')` and check to see what functionality is lost by killing jQuery...

Comment: Thanks Elias. Instead of JSON.parse() I ended up using a 2nd RegExp: `/(?:'(.*?)(?:(?:'\s*,\s*)|(?:'\s*\))))|(?:"(.*?)(?:(?:"\s*,\s*)|(?:"\s*\))))/` and removed any nulls and undefineds from the result and assigned that to an array that I passed to apply.

Comment: I was thinking about this just this morning, on my way to work. JSON.parse was definitely going to be tricky when dealing with single vs double quotes. just a thought on your expression though: why not use `/?:['"](.*?)(?:(?:['"]\s*,\s*)|(?:['"]\s*\)))/`, instead of repeating the same expression twice?

Comment: I did it like that to make it more reliable. When they're together `['"]` a string such as `'"Hey", he said.'` would return `"Hey` but if there are 2 seperate patterns seperated by an OR, it returns `"Hey", he said.` So it's long and annoying but at least it works. :) I also changed the RegExp to accept numbers not in any quotes. `/(?:'(.*?)(?:(?:'\s*,\s*)|(?:'\s*\))))|(?:"(.*?)(?:(?:"\s*,\s*)|(?:"\s*\))))|(?:([^\('"].*?)(?:(?:\s*,\s*)|(?:\s*\))))/` But if there is a way to shrink this down, I'm all ears. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use one of these methods:

- apply

  `var result = function.apply(thisArg[, argsArray]);`
- call

  `var result = fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]]);`

Here is the sample:

```
var Sample = function() {
var that = this;

this.sampleMethod = function() {
    return alert("Hello!");
};

this.sampleMethod2 = function(){

    that["sampleMethod"].apply(that);
};  
};

var objImpl = new Sample();

objImpl.sampleMethod2(); //you will get a message from 'sampleMethod()'
```

Comment: And where are you starting from a string formatted like `.attr('arg','arg')`?

Comment: that["sampleMethod"].apply(that);

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The OP is looking for a eval-less way to start from a string like `var someStr = 'setAttr("id","foobar")';` and use it to call the `setAttr` method on a jQuery object and pass the arguments correctly, yours doesn't do that

Comment: Another thing: why are you using `that`, rather then this? I don't see the point in that/`that` here, in both methods, `this` will reference the `Sample` object anyway

Comment: I agree, in a particular case 'that' is redundant. It is actual when 'Sample' class contains, for example, jQuery event bindings ($(document).click(function(){...});) to call public functions of 'Sample' class.

Comment: I thought as much, `that` is definitely (and sadly) a requirement when using closures

Answer (score 0):

Eval does what you want to do. Eval is evil, however, because you should not do what you want to do.

[Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea)