# Call back function basics - javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

I need to write a function:

```
function doTestConnCall(param1, param2, callbackfun)
```

param1 & param2 are parameters which I have used inside the function. 
The 3rd parameter - `callbackfun` is a function which to be called after finishing `doTestConnCall`

1. How to achieve this?
2. Is it possible to pass 2 callbacks inside a single method. Say `doTestConnCall(param1,callback1,callback2)`

Think I am missing some basics. Could any one lead me

Comment: Do you mean to call javascript function from string? Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
callbackfun(argument1, argument2);
```

or:

```
callbackfun.apply(this, [ argument1, argument2 ]);
```

or:

```
callbackfun.call(this, argument1, argument2);
```

The same can be done with multiple callbacks.  For example:

```
callback1.call(this);
callback2.call(this);
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

And: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 0):

1. Call any callback whenever appropriate in the function you are writing--in the case you described, after it completes its core work.
2. Yes, of course.  Call them one after another.

   ```
   function multipleCallbacks(arg, arg, callback1, callback2) {
       // Do some stuff

       // Do error checking in the real world if you need to be tolerant
       callback1();
       callback2();   
   }
   ```

Comment: @musa Thanks for the edit, I was trying to fix it but sometimes markdown is evil.  Frankly I don't see what you put in is different than what I was doing, but what can you do.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in JS are top level constructs. That means `function hello() {}` is the same as `var hello = function() {};`. So if you want to pass `hello` to the function above, you can just call `doTestConnCall(param1, param2, hello)` after you have defined `hello()` using either method above.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you achieve it.

It is possible to pass what ever you want to as a method parameter.

```
function doTestConnCall(param1, param2, callbackfun){
   DO YOUR LOGIC
   callbackfun() // CALL YOUR CALLBACK
}
```