# Javascript remove HTML

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I have this HTML code, and I want to remove part of the `onclick` events (the part after the `;`). How should I do this?

I already got the object in an array:

```
document.getElementById(labels[i].htmlFor)
```

HTML:

```
<td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
<input id="ui_cbSubParam_LimitsColumnsTo" type="checkbox" name="ui_cbSubParam_LimitsColumnsTo" checked="checked" onclick="ControlConditionalEnable23(true);setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ui_cbSubParam_LimitsColumnsTo\',\'\')', 0)" />
<label for="ui_cbSubParam_LimitsColumnsTo">Use Default</label>
</td>
```

Comment: You probably want to pull the onclick function out to a javascript file/script tag.  Then you can set a condition to determine whether to run the second command or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just reset the onclick:

```
var btn = document.getElementById(labels[i].htmlFor);
if(btn.onclick == true) {
   btn.onclick = function () { ControlConditionalEnable23(true); };
};
```

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to get the name of the function already asigned to the onclick event? the '23' changes in every form.

Comment: I think you can do something like btn.getAttribute('onclick')

Comment: then you may need this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call

Comment: Im having some issues with getAttribute, I try btn.getAttribute("onclick").substring(aNumber) but it says the object doesnt support the method, then I try string(btn.getAttribute("onclick")) it says it's expecting an object... what does getAttribute return?

Comment: the getAttrbute should return a string have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/FdPP2/2/ it shows how to get your function from the onclick and then fire it