# jquery: use string as function (error: string is not a function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, each

The code below generates click functions for each given ID in the single-line array, using the uncommented code, I get the error "string is not a function". If I uncomment the commented code, and comment the single-line array, it does work well. However I prefer the approach with the singe-line array, to me, for obvious reasons.

Can anyone give me some good advice? Am I on the right path?

Thanks in advance.

```
// callme
function callme() {
    alert("call me");
    return true;
}

// create javascript object
//var adapter = {};
// set values - key contains: ID associated with link, button or tab - value contains:   the function to call
//adapter['callme'] = callme;
//adapter['callme1'] = callme1;
//adapter['callme2'] = callme2;
//adapter['callme3'] = callme3;

var adapter = ["callme", "callme1", "callme2", "callme3"];

// foreach the object - key as ID - value as associated function
$.each(adapter, function(index, value) {
    // click on listed ID
  $("#"+ value).click(function() {
    // call associated function
        value();    
    });
    // end foreach
});
```

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call

Comment: is everyone absolutely sure this is a duplicate? this one is far from duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string - I dont understand. Function name between quotes? Arguments? Please elaborate someone

Comment: If I use: window["value"](); I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'value' "

Comment: Then do `self[value]();`

Comment: tried, returns same error

Answer (score 3):

It depends a bit on the scope, but the general idea is that you can use the square bracket notation to get a reference to the function and execute it. For example, the following:

```
window[value]();
```

would be equivalent to `callme()` for the first iteration, assuming the `callme` function is globally scoped (a property of the `window` object).

Comment: thanks, I've already tried that, I got the error "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'callme' of object [object global] is not a function" - so the callme function is probably not globally scoped. How should I do that?

Comment: @MaartenHartman I'd need to see more of your code to determine the correct scope, or you can move it outside of any closures (so just inside the `<script>` and `</script>` tags) so it *is* globally scoped.

Comment: the code displayed above is all there is (except for $(document).ready(function($) {). Without <script> tags, and loaded into the header.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `eval` to evaluate the string as a function, although you have to be careful security-wise. Evaluating a string coming from user input or a form submission could make your site vulnerable to [cross-site scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_site_scripting) and [session hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack).

Example:

```
eval(value + "();"); //call "value" as a function
```

Comment: thanks, I've found this suggestion as well, but nearly everyone said: do not use eval! I've tried it, and it indeed works well. But I prefer a safer solution.

Comment: As long as you are sure that you are not parsing user input, it is safe.