# Dynamic onchange with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to use jQuery to dynamically populate the onChange attribute in a text field to run multiple functions. However i get an error in the console stating

```
TypeError: required is not a function
```

When i type into the console required('test'); the function exists and returns true.

HTML

```
  <input id="test">
```

jQuery

```
var list_of_functions = get_validation(); //this returns a string "required('test'); valid('test');"  
$('#test').attr('onChange', list_of_functions);
```

Then when i go and change the fieldtext, I get an error that the function doesnt exist. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: `$('#test').change(function() { ... });`. Always a good idea to check the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: Why in the world are you trying to bind event listeners like this? And why use function names rather than handles directly to the functions?

Comment: ^ this would not work, whats inside the function is dynamically long

Comment: @MattBall aren't you supposed to be at work?

Comment: Ouch! Return a *function*, not a string, and use [*event handlers*](http://api.jquery.com/on) instead of that `onChange` attribute…

Comment: et tu, @Andbdrew `;-)`

Comment: my list of functions comes from an ajax call in string form. That is all i have to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all the super helpful comments. I have found a better alternative to what I was attempting to do. 
[How to turn a String into a javascript function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call)