# Evaluate one specific function in a JavaScript statement

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to mimic lazy evaluation in JavaScript by evaluating one specific function call in an expression, while leaving the other functions as-is. Is it possible to evaluate just one function in an expression without evaluating the other functions (so that all of the other function calls in the expression are left as-is)?

Here's the function I'm trying to implement:

```
function evaluateSpecificFunction(theExpression, functionsToEvaluate){
    //Evaluate one specific function in the expression, and return the new expression, with one specific function being evaluated
}
```

For example:

```
evaluateSpecificFunction("addTwoNumbers(1, 2) + getGreatestPrimeFactor(10)", addTwoNumbers);
//This should return "3 + getGreatestPrimeFactor(10)", since only one of the functions is being evaluated

evaluateSpecificFunction("addTwoNumbers(1, 2) + getGreatestPrimeFactor(10)", getGreatestPrimeFactor);
//This should return "addTwoNumbers(1, 2) + 5";
```

Comment: You'll have to do the parsing, here, or use a replacement.

Comment: you can parse the param1 string

Comment: @MikeHometchko Which string is the "param1 string"?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: @flup I'm basically trying to mimic [lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) in JavaScript.

Comment: This is the wrong approach. You should use thunks or promises.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://underscorejs.org/#memoize

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is play with [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and a regular expression :

```
function getGreatestPrimeFactor(n) {
  return n*2;
}

function transform(s, f) {
  return s.replace(new RegExp(f+"\\(([^\\)]*)\\)", "g"), function(m, args) {
    return window[f].apply(null, args.split(',').map(function(v){
       return parseFloat(v)
    }));
  });
}


var result = transform(
    "addTwoNumbers(1, 2) + getGreatestPrimeFactor(10)",
    "getGreatestPrimeFactor"
);
```

This example assume you deal only with numeric parameters.

[**Demonstration** (open the console)](http://jsbin.com/oyocij/5/edit)

Of course this code mostly demonstrate the idea, you should, for example, store the functions in a dedicated object and not the global context (`window`).

**EDIT** : the new version can handle more than one replacement.

Comment: Why not just use `return eval(m);`? It might be appropriate here. And btw, your regex deals badly with nested expressions :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Because `window[f]` may be faster than `eval`.

Comment: @Bergi Dealing with nested expression would imply parsing the expression, not just playing with regex. And when I can avoid `eval`, I avoid it...

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Sure it is, but speed doesn't seem to be a concern here. And that `window[f]` thing limits your expressions a lot, in this case to literal number arguments…

Comment: @dystroy: I didn't mean parsing them, but just avoiding them (with `[^()]*`)

Comment: @Bergi Limiting the expressions here is probably a desired feature. I suppose the real application would exploit a dictionary of functions. But of course this could be simplified with eval.

Comment: Perhaps a better approach would be to implement a function that would return its own function call as a string. (For example, `getOwnFunctionCall("3", 3)` would return the string `"getOwnFunctionCall(\"3\", 3)`. Then each function in the expression, except for the function to be evaluated, would need to be temporarily redefined, so that it would return its own function call as a string.