# JavaScript - Throw Exception containing variable name

Tags: javascript

How can I throw an exception using a variable within the exception name during the `throw new` statement?

I have a list of exceptions that I'm trying to throw depending on whether or not one variable is zero in length. The name of the exception, for example, contains the variable name.

**Works**

```
if (X.length === 0)
{
    throw new NoXException();
}

if (Y.length === 0)
{
    throw new NoYException();
}

if (Z.length === 0)
{
    throw new NoZException();
}
```

**Doesn't work**

```
var X = 'Oh';
var Y = 'Hai';
var Z = '';

// Contains "NoZException"
var ex = "No" + ((X.length != 0) ? ((Y.length != 0) ? 'Z' : 'Y') : 'X') + "Exception";

// Throwing ex gives an error
throw new ex();
```

Comment: Well, `ex` is a string, not a function.

Comment: `throw new window[ex]()` ?

Comment: *Also, I love my ternaries. Leave them alone.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to convert a string to a function and create a new instance of a variable, which won't work.

There are ways to get a function corresponding to a string: [How to turn a String into a javascript function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call)

But a better way to go about this would be to simply do the first if statement, or convert it to a switch.

For a global variable:

```
// Set up in global scope, not in the scope of something else.
var NoXException = function () { ... }

var variable = "No" + getMissing() + "Exception";
throw new window[variable]()
```

For a variable that's stored within another's scope:

```
var exceptions = {}
exceptions.NoXException = function () { ... }

var variable = "No" + getMissing() + "Exception";
throw new exceptions[variable]()
// Alternatively
throw new window['exceptions'][variable]()
```

Comment: The `NoXException`, `NoYException` and `NoZException` classes exist though?

Comment: But simply creating a string won't convert that string into that corresponding class. You can do a look up as the link in my answer shows, using `window[ex]`.

Comment: Couldn't get it working: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B859C/).

Comment: @Jimbo: That's because `NoZException` is not global in your example. All the code is *local* to the `load` event handler. If you want the code to be global, select `No wrap` in the settings.

Comment: Could you please provide an example to make your comment work? Although marked as a duplicate, I can imagine other's finding this post useful with "exception" being in the name, even if they are just functions ;) Stuck here: http://jsfiddle.net/B859C/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/B859C/3/ Now that you have a variable defined, you can look up the exception using the variable as an array. `class['attribute']`

Comment: Perfect! Cheers @Blam - want me to add this to your answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @Jimbo: Do you see the two select boxes on the left hand side? One says "onLoad". You have to select "No wrap - in <head>" or "No wrap - in <body>". http://jsfiddle.net/B859C/4/. Have a look at the jsFiddle documentation: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-settings-sidebar.

Comment: @FelixKling Ahh, great thanks. I'm actually going to be using non-global stuff within individual classes - OOP wasn't the focus of this ;) but your help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: @Jimbo: Good, I would not advice for global variables anyway ;)

Comment: @Blam: FYI, the variable is not used "as an array". This way (`foo['bar']`) of accessing properties is called *bracket notation* (and is equivalent to *dot notation* (`foo.bar`)). It just happens that bracket notation is the only way to access array elements. I'm just saying this so that no one thinks this has anything to do with arrays (and confuses arrays and objects).

Comment: You're right I just wasn't sure of the terminology, thanks :)