# Call javascript function encoded in a string

Tags: javascript, function, eval, tostring

If I put a function into a string like this:

```
var functionString = function (message) {
    console.log(message);
}.toString();
```

Is there any way to convert the string back to a function and call it?
I tried

```
eval(functionString)
```

which returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token", and

```
functionString.call(this, "HI!");
```

which returns 'undefined is not a function'.

Is that even possible in javascript?

Thanks in advance for any reply!

EDIT: The point of this question is that the function has been converted into a string using toString(). So

```
console.log(functionString);
```

returns this string:
"function (message) {console.log(message);}"

Can I transform the string back into a function and call it? That's the problem I am trying to solve.
Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you'd post exactly what's in the string.

Comment: You could just do "return message.toString()" inside the function

Comment: Is it possible, yes it can be, but what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call

Comment: epascarello, I would like to convert the string back to a function. Brian, I don't want to call an existing function. I would like to convert the entire string into a function.

Comment: @BrianShamblen this is a different question than that one. In that question, they have the name of a function they want to call.

Comment: One is forced to question *why* you want to do this. Evaluating arbitrary code is considered dangerous in almost every language that has the ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `functionString` contains exactly the string

`"function (message) { console.log(message); }"`

Evaluating it as-is does present JavaScript engine with incorrect syntax (there is no name for this function). JavaScript expects construct like `function <name>(<params>) { }`. Alternatively, you can use anonymous function (i.e. no name present), but only as a parameter or in a context of evaluating expression. The minimal typical evaluating expression would be `(function() {})()` If you want to get fancy, `!function() {}` is also ok - the exclamation mark in front turns it into boolean expression that requires function evaluation before negating the output.

So, in your example this will work:

`eval("("+functionString+")('abc')");`

because then you do anonymous function call - something JavaScript can live with.

Alternatively, you can also use just brackets, then you need to assign the result to something you can use later:

```
var foo = eval("("+functionString+")");
foo('ddd');
```

Here is a little proof / playground to learn about it:
http://jsfiddle.net/Exceeder/ydann6b3/

Comment: Works, thanks! Could you tell me what I should google for to learn more about this, for example the +-wrapping of functionString?

Comment: @user1840267 for eval(), it always makes sense to print the actual string you evaluate, then copy-paste it in the editor of your choice in empty .js file and see if it is syntactically correct.

Comment: Ah, I see, he is simply wrapping the function into parenthesis! Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're nearly there, but you're missing something.

When we call toString() on your function, we get

```
"function (message) {
    console.log(message);
}"
```

which we can then eval. However, we're just creating an anonymous function object here; we won't be able to call it!

If we instead to something like:

```
var functionString = "var restoredFunc = " + function (message) {
    console.log(message);
}.toString();
```

We can then do the following

```
eval(functionString);
// prints "hello!" to console
restoredFunc("hello!");
```

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible in JavaScript but you can't `eval` anonymous function without assignment

So you go through it like so

```
var functionString = function (message) {
    console.log(message);
}.toString();

eval("myfunction =" + functionString)

myfunction("Hello World!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `functionString` is a string that looks like

```
"function (message) {
    console.log(message);
}"
```

You could covert that string to an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) using string concatenation, similar to below.

```
(function (message) {
        console.log(message);
})("HI!");
```

and then eval that.  Here is the result from Chrome's JavaScript console:

```
eval('(' + functionString + ')("HI!")')
HI!
```