# JavaScript string of sub functions to actual functions

Tags: javascript, string, function

I learned I can call functions by a string representing the function name. Example here: http://www.sitepoint.com/call-javascript-function-string-without-using-eval/

My question is, how can I call the `SubTest` function in this case:

```
  function Test() {
     this.SubTest = function() { }
  }

  var functionString = 'Test.SubTest';
```

It doesn't work with `window[functionString]`.

I even tried this (it's basic; just for testing) but it returns `false`:

```
function GetFunction(functionName) {
    var functions = functionName.split('.');
    if ( functions.length === 1 ) {
        var functionObj = window[functions[0]];
        if ( typeof functionObj === 'function' )
            return functionObj;
        return false;
    }
    else if ( functions.length > 1 ) {
        var functionObj = window[functions[0]];
        for ( var i = 1; i < functions.length; i++ ) {
          functionObj = functionObj[functions[i]];
        }
        if ( typeof functionObj === 'function' )
            return functionObj;
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

var functionName = 'Test.SubTest'; // from the above code example
var functionObj = GetFunction(functionName); // returns false
```

**Update:**

Found this: [How to turn a String into a javascript function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call#answer-12380392) but the `getFunctionFromString` still doesn't work.

Comment: You can't use Test.SubTest directly because SubTest is added on Test on it's initialization, you need to have `var t = new Test()` before you can use this function. `GetFunction("Test.SubTest")` work if you had `Test.SubTest = function(){}`

Comment: Yup, that's the correct answer. Now it makes sense. Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is `Test.SubTest` does not exist

`SubTest` is a property defined in the constructor function `Test`

That mean that the only way to access this function is to define an object

```
var t = new Test();
t.SubTest();
```

---

The function `GetFunction("Test.SubTest")` would work if the function was static, like :

```
function Test() {}
Test.SubTest = function(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because `typeof window['Test.SubTest']` is undefined... so, you need to instantiate the super object to call it's sub function(encapsulated function indeed). See bellow code

```
  .....
      else if ( functions.length > 1 ) {
    var functionObj = window[functions[0]];
    for ( var i = 1; i < functions.length; i++ ) {
      functionObj = eval('new '+functionObj+'().'+functions[i]);
    }
    if ( typeof functionObj === 'function' )
        return functionObj;
    return false;
    }
  .....
```

**EDITS**:
I your comment stated you don't want to use `eval` consider the following solution

```
  .....
      else if ( functions.length > 1 ) {
    var functionObj = window[functions[0]];
    for ( var i = 1; i < functions.length; i++ ) {
       functionObj =new functionObj()[functions[i]];
    }
    if ( typeof functionObj === 'function' )
        return functionObj;
    return false;
    }
  .....
```

And here is the complete code for test

```
     function Test() {
       this.SubTest = function() { 
        this.subsubtest=function(){ alert('subsubtest')}
     }
    }

    var functionString = 'Test.SubTest.subsubtest';

    function GetFunction(functionName) {
      var functions = functionName.split('.');
      if ( functions.length === 1 ) {
          var functionObj = window[functions[0]];
          if ( typeof functionObj === 'function' )
              return functionObj;
          return false;
      }
      else if ( functions.length > 1 ) {
          var functionObj = window[functions[0]];
          for ( var i = 1; i < functions.length; i++ ) {
           functionObj =new functionObj()[functions[i]];
          }
          if ( typeof functionObj === 'function' )
              return functionObj;
          return false;
      }
      return false;
  }

  var functionName = 'Test.SubTest.subsubtest';  
  var functionObj = GetFunction(functionName); 
  alert(typeof functionObj);//function
```

Comment: Yeah, not gonna use `eval`.

Comment: `eval` il not required, `new functionObj()[functions[i]]()` should work but this notation and the for loop makes no sense as you could not use this method for `static` functions

Comment: As you edited your answer, could you tell what is the point of the for loop ?

Comment: @VjS You didn't mention that! Now I edited my answer with non-eval code... Thank you Hacketo => :'( static functions

Comment: Sorry; `eval` is usually a bad idea and I had no idea JavaScript had `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Test = function () {
  this.SubTest = function () {}
} 

var obj = new Test()

obj['SubTest']()
```

or

```
Test = function () {}
Test.SubTest = function () {}

window['Test']['SubTest']()
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: If you have read the description of his problem, it is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Sure, but a good answer, one that gets upvotes, *explains* the reasoning and logic.