# Calling function within function from a string variable with arguments

Tags: javascript

I would like to call a function within a function from a string variable with arguments.

Let me demonstrate what I would like with adding some code

```
var myFunction = function() {
    var innerFunction = function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }

    return {
        run: function(data) {
            innerFunction(data);
        }
    }
};

var myString = "myFunction.run()";
```

If I don't want to pass variable than it is quite easy;

```
var callFunction = new Function(myString);
callFunction();
```

If I can pass a variable without using function within a function;

```
function myFunction(data) {
    alert(data);
}

var myString = "myFunction";
window[myString]("Hello World!");
```

However this is not what I want. Could anyone enlighten me about calling a function within a function from a `string` variable with passing arguments to it?

Comment: This would still help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/359910/2466168

Comment: If you found solution by yourself then please post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162944/javascript-string-of-sub-functions-to-actual-functions/29163303#29163303

Comment: @phts I tried but it warned me to add it as a comment so I ended up editing my question

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful

```
var myfun = function(){
 console.log('Hello');
}

window['myfun']();
```

Output:  `Hello`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems posting on SOF helps me to think better.

I forgot to try this one;

```
var functionName = myString.split('.');
window[functionName[0]][functionName[1]]("Hello World");
```

It works as expected. Thank you everyone.