# can D3 chaining be assembled with indirection?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

```js
chart
  .width(w)
  .height(h)
```

is it possible in some way to use indirection when chaining? I need to something like

```js
var n = 80;
var ind = "width(' + n + ')";

chart
  .[ind]
```

... obviously not legal code but hoping it describes question.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do. You can simply define a function to set the width.

Comment: I am dynamically building charts from a json template. I am setting values from the data e.g. .centerBar(parms.isCb), but I want to be able to add ".yAxisLabel(parms.yAxLbl)" to the chart.

Comment: What you are really asking is how do I call a JavaScript function stored in a string.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call).  I wouldn't do this unless it's *really*, *really* need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `chart.options` for that:

```
chart.options({width: w, height: h});
```

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.baseMixin+options

Further, if you're reading the options from somewhere,

```
var opts = {};
while(/* read option opt, val from somewhere */)
    options[opt] = val;
chart.options(opts);
```

Comment: looking at this now ... does this mean that we can build complete charts dynamically from just a list of parms e.g. chart='pie", width=300, dmnsn="custs" etc? I was a little surprised to find that dc does not inherit .attr("...", "...") or .call() from d3.

Comment: Yeah, dc objects are not d3 objects, they are psuedo-classes which contain d3 objects. So I don't think `.attr` and `.call` are appropriate on the charts themselves (although you can `chart.select(...).attr(...).call(...)`).

Comment: As for the dynamic creation, yes, I think so, but I haven't tried it myself. I bet it won't work for everything - how would you do axes for example. IIUC this is how [angular-dc](https://github.com/TomNeyland/angular-dc) works (and users of that library have contributed to `.options`).

Comment: excellent stuff! Sounds best to create base charts with axes and then expand from there with template parms. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It is more a JavaScript question than d3.js.

You can set the function name dynamically in JS.

```
var n = 80;
var fnc = "width";
chart[func](n);
```

Do I understand your problem well?

Comment: trying to add ".yAxisLabel(parms.yAxLbl)" as above, I tried all kinds of [] in the equation but only got errors.