# How to remove double quotes from json string in javascript/Jquery

Tags: jquery

Please go through below Jquery method which returns script string, there I want to remove double quotes for **Handler** Key Value (which is function)

```
_GetOptionsScrpit: function () {
        var sb = [];
        var self = this;
        var o = self.options;
        sb.push({
            "key": o.key,
            "amount": o.amount,
            "name": o.name,
            "description": o.description,
            "image": o.image,
            "order_id":o.order_id,
             "handler": 'function(response) {alert(response)}',
            "prefill": {
                "name": o.prefillname,
                "email": o.prefillemail,
                "contact": o.prefillcontact,
                "method": self._GetDefaultPrefilMethod()
            },
            //"notes": o.notes,
            "theme": {
                "color": o.color
            },
            "method": {
                "netbanking": o.IsNetbanking,
                "wallet": o.IsWallet,
                "card": o.IsCard,
                "upi": o.IsUPI
            },
            "modal": {
                "escape": o.modalescape,
                "backdropclose": o.modalbackdropclose
            },

        });

        return '<script type="text/javascript"> var options = ' + JSON.stringify(sb[0]) + '   ;';
        console.log('<script type="text/javascript"> var options = ' + JSON.stringify(sb[0]) + '  ;');

    }
```

Method is returning

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = {
    "key": "rzp_test_Mh1t1NPPlSbufV",
    "amount": "10000",
    "name": "Merchant Name",
    "description": "Purchase Description",
    "image": "https://your-awesome-site.com/your_logo.jpg",
    "order_id": "",
    "handler": "function(response) {alert(response)}",
    "prefill": {
        "name": "ggg",
        "email": "ggg@ggg.com",
        "contact": "9441239494",
        "method": "netbanking"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": ""
    },
    "method": {
        "netbanking": "true",
        "wallet": "false",
        "card": "false",
        "upi": false
    },
    "modal": {
        "escape": true,
        "backdropclose": true
    }
};
var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
document.getElementById("rzp-button1").onclick = function(e) {
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault()
};
```

Kindly do need full and I need output like below (handler value no double quotes)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = {
    "key": "rzp_test_Mh1t1NPPlSbufV",
    "amount": "10000",
    "name": "Merchant Name",
    "description": "Purchase Description",
    "image": "https://your-awesome-site.com/your_logo.jpg",
    "order_id": "",
    "handler": function(response) {alert(response)},
    "prefill": {
        "name": "ggg",
        "email": "ggg@ggg.com",
        "contact": "9441239494",
        "method": "netbanking"
    },
    "theme": {
        "color": ""
    },
    "method": {
        "netbanking": "true",
        "wallet": "false",
        "card": "false",
        "upi": false
    },
    "modal": {
        "escape": true,
        "backdropclose": true
    }
};
var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
document.getElementById("rzp-button1").onclick = function(e) {
    rzp1.open();
    e.preventDefault()
};
```

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912596/how-to-turn-a-string-into-a-javascript-function-call

Comment: You could search the value _with_ quotes and replace it by the value _without_ quotes.